# ZBar cannot decode a valid barcode from an image

Tags: c++, zbar

I'm looping over a video containing Code 128 barcodes, frame by frame reading the barcode values. ZBar works great for most of the video frames and then comes across one it cannot decode the barcode from.

This frame is just like the others, a barcode on a perfect white background.

Frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur4eQ.jpg

With the above image this example code does not print out any decoded barcodes, but it should. (I'm using C++ but this simple Python snippet demonstrates the same issue)

```py
import zbar
import zbar.misc
import cv2
from PIL import Image

image = cv2.imread('coded-img.jpg', 0)

scanner = zbar.Scanner()
results = scanner.scan(image)
print(results)
for result in results:
    print(result.data, zbar.misc.upca_is_valid(result.data.decode('ascii')))
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening, or anyway I can alter the way I'm writing the barcode to the image to fix it? My barcode is 100% valid as it works with this online reader https://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/

Answer (score 0):

My 'solution' was to stop using zbar and use this instead https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp